# How to structure an Erlang OTP UDP server

Tags: erlang, udp, erlang-otp

I am just reading *Manning's Erlang & OTP In Action*. Very good book, I think. It contains a nice TCP server example but I'd like to write a UDP server. This is how I structured my app so far.

```
my_app                        % app behaviour
|-- my_sup                    % root supervisor 
    |-- my_server.erl         % gen_server to open UDP connection and dispatch
    |-- my_worker_sup         % simple_one_to_one supervisor to start workers
        |-- my_worker_server  % gen_server worker
```

So, `my_app` starts `my_sup`, which in turn starts `my_worker_sup` and `my_server`. The UDP connection is opened in `my_server` in active mode such that `handle_info/2` is invoked on each new UDP message in response to which I call `my_worker_sup:start_child/2` to pass the message to a new worker process for processing. (The last call to `start_child/2` is in fact, as per the book's recommendation, wrapped in an API function to hide some of the details, but this is essentially what happens.)

Am I suffering from OTP fever? Should the `my_worker_server` really implement the gen_server behaviour? Do I need `my_worker_sup` at all?

I set it up in like this so that I can use `my_worker_sup` as a factory via the `start_child/2` call but I only use the worker's `init/1` and `handle_info(timeout,State)` functions to first setup state and then to process the message before shutting the worker down.

Should I just spawn the worker directly? Is another behaviour better suited, perhaps?

Thanks,
HC

Comment: I think I might have found the answer to how to fit the worker into OTP as a 'special process' here http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/spec_proc.html#id72749

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key answer to this question is: "*how do you want your application to crash?*"

If a worker dies, then what should happen? If this should stop everything, including the UDP connection, then surely you can just spawn_link them under the my_server directly, no supervisor tree needed. But if you want them to be able to gracefully restart or something else, then the above diagram is usually better. Perhaps add a monitor on the workers from my_server so it can keep a book of who is alive.

In my utp erlang library, I have almost the same construction. A master handles the UDP socket and forwards to workers based on a routing table kept in ETS. Each worker keeps a connection state and can handle the incoming information.

Since you don't track state, then your best bet is probably to run via `proc_lib:spawn_link` and then hook them to the s_1_1 supervisor as transient processes. That way, you will force too many crashes to be propagated up the supervisor tree but allow them to exit with `normal`. This allows you to have them run exactly once.

Note that you could also handle everything directly in the my_server, but then you will not be able to process data concurrently. This may or may not be acceptable. The general rule is to spawn a new process when you have concurrent work that needs to be executed next to each other, blocks or otherwise *behaves* in some way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. No, I don't want the entire server to crash. I am trying to write a DNS server https://github.com/hcvst/erlang-dns. I didn't even think of possibly having to track connections. What's that library you are talking of. Can I study it? Thanks again, HC

Comment: Sure it is: https://github.com/jlouis/erlang-utp/blob/master/src/utp_sup.erl - `gen_utp` runs the accept queue and the socket. `gen_utp_decoder` is the decoder and dispatcher. Kept separate to handle crashes. Finally the worker pool contains the dispatched workers. Study the book keeping of process tables - but my thought process might have been wrong, so beware.